# ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded - angular single spa

Tags: angular, single-spa

I am facing this issue when running npm run build (I am using single spa application), recently I have converted this angular application into single-spa and I have also upgraded the angular version to 10.2.5:

[image]

[image]

I have spent at least 3 days trying to resolve this issue, any ideas about how to resolve this issue?

Here is my package.json file

```css
{
  "name": "fmp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "npm run env -s && ng build --prod",
    "start": "npm run env -s && ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint && stylelint \"src/**/*.scss\" --syntax scss && htmlhint \"src\" --config .htmlhintrc",
    "test": "npm run env -s && ng test",
    "test:ci": "npm run env -s && npm run lint -s && ng test --configuration=ci",
    "e2e": "npm run env -s && ng e2e",
    "translations:extract": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/translations/template.json --format=json --clean --sort --marker extract",
    "docs": "hads ./docs -o",
    "env": "ngx-scripts env npm_package_version",
    "generate": "ng generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/elements": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.11.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "16.0.2",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.2.4",
    "ag-grid-angular": "21.2.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "21.2.1",
    "angular-tree-component": "8.4.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "codemirror": "5.49.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "enhanced-resolve": "4.1.0",
    "flot": "3.2.10",
    "ika.jvectormap": "1.0.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jqcloud2": "2.0.3",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "2.4.0",
    "jquery.browser": "0.1.0",
    "jquery.flot.tooltip": "0.9.0",
    "jqwidgets-ng": "^8.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "modernizr": "3.7.1",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "5.0.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-material-dropdown": "0.10.1",
    "ng2-table": "1.3.2",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "5.1.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "8.0.0",
    "ngx-select-ex": "3.7.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^3.0.3",
    "npm": "^6.11.3",
    "popper.js": "1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "screenfull": "5.0.0",
    "simple-line-icons": "2.4.1",
    "spinkit": "1.2.5",
    "summernote": "0.8.12",
    "sweetalert": "2.1.2",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "tslib": "1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.8",
    "@material/top-app-bar": "^3.2.0",
    "@ngneat/spectator": "^4.11.1",
    "@ngx-rocket/scripts": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/codemirror": "0.0.77",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.139",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "5.0.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "karma-read-json": "1.1.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "loaders.css": "0.1.2",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "ng-bullet": "^1.0.3",
    "prettier": "^1.14.0",
    "protractor": "5.4.4",
    "stylelint": "~9.6.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "~3.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "~18.2.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "~3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "8.4.1",
    "tslint": "5.20.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.14.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.1.7"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": "*.scss",
        "options": {
          "singleQuote": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the angular.json :

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "mfe-fmp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "docker/dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src\\main.single-spa.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/apple-touch-icon.png",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [

            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "extra-webpack.config.js",
              "libraryName": "mfe-fmp",
              "libraryTarget": "umd"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mfe-fmp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "mfe-fmp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mfe-fmp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [

            ],
            "styles": [

            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/apple-touch-icon.png",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "e2e": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "mfe-fmp:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "mfe-fmp"
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Just a thought: maybe updating the other libraries will fix your issue. For example, the Angular Material version it should be the same as the Angular Core version

Comment: @ionut-t yes I will try to do that

Comment: @Drenai sorry I mean converting the angular app into a micro front-end application using single-spa framework

Comment: Yep, @Drenai point is valid, was about to ask the same. Anyhow, I suggest you delete your current `node_modules`, `npm cache clean --force`, then `npm ci` to clean install

Comment: I am still facing this issue, any ideas about how it can be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, @Drenai point is valid, was about to ask the same. Anyhow, I suggest you delete your current `node_modules`, `npm cache clean --force`, then `npm ci` to clean install.

If you want an interactive interface to guide you thru the process of updating your apps, this link to an interactive interface is part of Angular projects and it will help you specifing the right commands, dependencies, and versions. https://update.angular.io/